# Can a bank force you to use their app in order to use their services under the PSD2?

Tags: european-union

An online bank I am using (Qonto) contacted my recently by email to tell me that I will not be able to use my account from 5th July unless I install their app in my phone. They say it is mandatory for PSD2 compliance.

While I understand PSD2 may enforce security mechanisms, it surprises me that under the EU, an open standard is not promoted/enforced for banks (like One-Time-Password/OTP mechanisms).

Enforcing to use their app could be discriminatory since it assumes you can install it in your device (you may not have a compatible phone). Also, being a proprietary app, it could be used to track information about you that you do not want to share with your bank.

Can a European bank do this? Wouldn't PSD2 protect users from this somehow?

Comment: It seems to me that PSD2 compliance is largely irrelevant to this question. A bank is free to offer some services and not offer other services; [Monzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monzo) for example has only ever offered accounts through their smartphone apps. If the law doesn't force Monzo to allow customers to log in through a browser on a desktop PC, or operate physical branches where customers can talk to real people, then it doesn't force Qonto to do those things either. The only difference is that Qonto used to offer another service which they are now discontinuing.

Comment: Have you enquired what accomodation they make for disabled persons who cannot use a device?

Comment: Thanks @kaya3-supportthestrike, good point. ^^

Comment: @DaleM I have not. That could be interesting to know but it would not be my case (nor I'd like to pretend it is).

Comment: @Peque my point is, if they do (and they should) then it would be discriminatory to not let you use it too.

Comment: See also [Is there a standard for OTPs tied to transaction details (that has been implemented in apps/devices)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/226256/is-there-a-standard-for-otps-tied-to-transaction-details-that-has-been-implemen)

Comment: See also [Is 3DS compatible with secure 2FA technologies? (TOTP, WebAuthn)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/273801/is-3ds-compatible-with-secure-2fa-technologies-totp-webauthn)

Comment: @MichaelAltfield Thanks for the pointers and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PSD2 [article 4(30)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32015L2366#d1e1374-35-1) defines multifactor authentication :

> ‘strong customer authentication’ means an authentication based on the use of two or more elements categorised as knowledge (something only the user knows), possession (something only the user possesses) and inherence (something the user is) that are independent, in that the breach of one does not compromise the reliability of the others, and is designed in such a way as to protect the confidentiality of the authentication data;

---

The [EBA](https://www.eba.europa.eu/eba-publishes-an-opinion-on-the-elements-of-strong-customer-authentication-under-psd2) published an opinion about the means of 2FA that are compliant with the Strong Customer Authentication of the PDS2

> it surprises me that under the EU, an open standard is not promoted/enforced for banks (like One-Time-Password/OTP mechanisms).

OTP/TOTP is not a compliant way to conduct SCA because of :

> The EBA is also of the view that an OTP that contributes to providing evidence of possession would not constitute a knowledge element for approaches currently observed in the market. Indeed, knowledge, by contrast with possession, is an element that should exist prior to the initiation of the payment or the online access.

TOTP would be compliant if it used a non-transferrable token that is only useable on that device alone (which a normal SOTP isn't) :

> As stated in the EBA Opinion on the implementation of the RTS (paragraph 35), a device could be used as evidence of possession, provided that there is a ‘reliable means to confirm possession through the generation or receipt of a dynamic validation element on the device’. Evidence could, in this context, be provided through the generation of a one-time password (OTP), whether generated by a piece of software or by hardware, such as a token, text message (SMS) or push notification. In the case of an SMS, and as highlighted in Q&A 4039, the possession element ‘would not be the SMS itself, but rather, typically, the SIM-card associated with the respective mobile number’.

---

> Can a European bank do this?

App-based auth is compliant because :

> The EBA is of the view that approaches relying on mobile apps, web browsers or the exchange of
> (public and private) keys may also be evidence of possession, provided that they include a device-binding process that ensures a unique connection between the PSU’s app, browser or key and the device. This may, for instance, be through hardware crypto-security, web browser and mobile-device registration or keys stored in the secure element of a device

---

> Also, being a proprietary app, it could be used to track information about you that you do not want to share with your bank.

You need to read the Privacy Policy of the app/service and exert your country/EU consent modification/retraction right

> Can a European bank do this?

Why wouldn't they be allowed? There are many services that you can only access on a proprietary app.

> Wouldn't PSD2 protect users from this somehow?

PSD2 gives security requirements, not anything else

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! I will wait a bit before accepting in case someone else wants to share their thoughts. ^^

About the "There are many services that you can only access on a proprietary app" I thought maybe a bank was considered as a basic service and perhaps accessibility rules were enforced (to make sure, for example, non-smartphone-owner citizens can have a bank account and use its services without smartphone/digitization knowledge).

Comment: @Peque Is this the only bank in the county in question? That seems relevant.

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim It is an online bank. Previously accessible with a browser and a mobile phone but without requiring an app. Definitely not the only bank in the county. ^^

Comment: @Peque So you could access the basic service of banking by using another bank?

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim Yeah, definitely.

Comment: @Peque In all EU Countries I can think of,  Banks are business and are allowed to conduct busniess however they see fit. What might be a legal right is holding a bank **account**. which *may* have some provisions. Quanto being a business-catering bank only, those would never apply

Comment: Thanks @NicolasFormichella! ^^